UserWarning: X has feature names, but RandomForestClassifier was fitted without feature names warnings.warn(
Im creating a python program to detect Phishing websites. so i basically want the programm to say if a user input url is legit or phish using a dataset. im using the UCI IRVINE PHISHING WEBSITES dataset.
so I have 2 issues,

first is no matter what URL i give im getting the same prediction and that is wrong.
2.im getting an error, UserWarning: X has feature names, but RandomForestClassifier was fitted without feature names
warnings.warn

please help me with this and im a complete beginner to python, i initially i got the code structure from an AI and sorry for the messed up code.

def get_user_url_features(url):    
    features = {}
    ext = tldextract.extract(url)

    # Existing Features:
    features['having_IP_Address'] = 1 if ext.domain.isdigit() else -1
    features['URL_Length'] = len(url) if len(url) < 75 else 1 
    features['having_At_Symbol'] = 1 if '@' in url else -1
    features['double_slash_redirecting'] = 1 if '//' in url[7:] else -1
    features['Prefix_Suffix'] = 1 if '-' in ext.domain else -1 
    features['Google_Index'] = check_google_index(url)  # We'll define this function
    

    feature_values = list(features.values()) 
    return feature_values 

def check_google_index(url):
    # Placeholder:  (You'll need to make a request to Google Search)
    
    domain = tldextract.extract(url).domain  # Extract just the domain

    google = "https://www.google.com/search?q=site:" + domain + "&hl=en"
    response = requests.get(google, cookies={"CONSENT": "YES+1"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    not_indexed = re.compile("did not match any documents")

    if soup(text=not_indexed):
        return -1  # Not indexed
    else:
        return 1  # Indexed
    return -1 
# 3. Prepare Features and Labels
X = data.drop('Result', axis=1)  
y = data['Result'] 

# 4. Split Data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=y)

# 5. Model Training
lr_model = LogisticRegression()
lr_model.fit(X_train.values, y_train)

rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
rf_model.fit(X_train.values, y_train)



# 2. Your Feature Extraction Function (Same as before)
def get_user_url_features(url):    
    features = {}
    ext = tldextract.extract(url)

    # Existing Features:
    features['having_IP_Address'] = 1 if ext.domain.isdigit() else -1
    features['URL_Length'] = len(url) if len(url) < 75 else 1 
    # ... Add your shortening service feature logic here ...
    features['having_At_Symbol'] = 1 if '@' in url else -1
    features['double_slash_redirecting'] = 1 if '//' in url[7:] else -1
    features['Prefix_Suffix'] = 1 if '-' in ext.domain else -1 
    features['Google_Index'] = check_google_index(url)  # We'll define this function
   

   

# Placeholders (We'll adjust these based on documentation)
    features['having_Sub_Domain'] = 0  # Placeholder: No subdomains detected 
    features['SSLfinal_State'] = -1  # Placeholder: HTTPS status unknown
    features['Domain_registeration_length'] = 0  # Placeholder: Unknown registration length
    features['Favicon'] = -1  # Placeholder: External favicon status unknown 
    features['port'] = -1  # Placeholder: Non-standard port status unknown 
    features['HTTPS_token'] = -1  # Placeholder: HTTPS token presence unknown
    features['Request_URL'] = 0  # Placeholder: Percentage unknown
    features['URL_of_Anchor'] = 0  # Placeholder: Percentage unknown
    features['Links_in_tags'] = 0  # Placeholder: Percentage unknown 
    features['SFH'] = -1  # Placeholder: SFH status unknown 
    features['Submitting_to_email'] = -1  # Placeholder: Submission status unknown 
    features['Abnormal_URL'] = -1  # Placeholder: Abnormal URL status unknown
    features['Redirect'] = 0  # Placeholder: Number of redirects unknown
    features['on_mouseover'] = -1  # Placeholder: Status bar change unknown
    features['RightClick'] = -1  # Placeholder: Right-click disabled status unknown
    features['popUpWidnow'] = -1  # Placeholder: Pop-up window status unknown
    features['Iframe'] = -1  # Placeholder: Iframe usage unknown
    features['age_of_domain'] = -1  # Placeholder: Domain age unknown 
    features['DNSRecord'] = -1  # Placeholder: DNS record status unknown
    features['web_traffic'] = -1  # Placeholder: Traffic rank unknown
    features['Page_Rank'] = -1  # Placeholder: PageRank unknown
    #features['Google_Index'] = -1  # Placeholder: Google Index status unknown
    features['Links_pointing_to_page'] = -1  # Placeholder: Number of links unknown
    features['Statistical_report'] = -1  # Placeholder: Statistical report status unknown
    features['Shortining_Service'] = -1  # Assuming -1 means no service detected




    feature_values = list(features.values()) 
    return feature_values


def check_google_index(url):
    # Placeholder:  (You'll need to make a request to Google Search)
    
    domain = tldextract.extract(url).domain  # Extract just the domain

    google = "https://www.google.com/search?q=site:" + domain + "&hl=en"
    response = requests.get(google, cookies={"CONSENT": "YES+1"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    not_indexed = re.compile("did not match any documents")

    if soup(text=not_indexed):
        return -1  # Not indexed
    else:
        return 1  # Indexed
    return -1 

# 3. Prediction Function
def predict_url(url):
    features = get_user_url_features(url)

    # Use the best performing model for prediction (modify if needed)
    prediction = loaded_rf_model.predict([features])[0]  
    confidence = loaded_rf_model.predict_proba([features])[0]

    result = "Phishing URL detected!" if prediction == -1 else "Legitimate URL detected."
    safe_percentage = confidence[1] * 100  # Assume class 1 is legitimate

please help me with this and im a complete beginner to python, i initially i got the code structure from an AI and sorry for the messed up code.



Thanks for posting. To increase your odds of getting useful help I would suggest making your question more narrow and targeted to one thing. Find the minimal code to reproduce your problem. Good luck!
